# Setting Headers for OAuth Authenticated User (Bearer)

Tags: swift, api, laravel, oauth, alamofire

I am experimenting on OAuth2 (on Laravel) & Swift with Alamofire. I successfully got token, however I couldn't set the headers to be able to get authenticate-specific data from Api.

Without Alamofire, I was setting this header and it was working.

```
func me(handler: (data: NSDictionary?, error: String?) -> Void)
{
    let url = NSURL(string: "/me", relativeToURL: self.baseUrl)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    if let t = self.getAccessToken()
    {
       request.setValue("Bearer \(t)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    }
}
```

However I didn't get what to do with Alamofire.

Now I can use `getAccessToken()` to get token as a `string`, but I got really confused adapting it to Alamofire style.

I tried this but doesn't pass the authentication middleware for a reason:

```
 let token = getAccessToken()
 print(token!)  // prints

 let headers = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(token)"]

 Alamofire.request(.GET, userDetailsEndpoint!, headers: headers)...
```

Still getting error `The resource owner or authorization server denied the request`

Comment: Do you found a solution ?

Comment: It's been 2 years after that, so I forgot how I managed to make it work. Try including this to headers too: `"Accept:" "application/json"`. Kolay gelsin

Comment: First, try something like Postman to make sure the api works, and then try to replicate it on Alamofire